# NSTimer fires but not incrementing (writing to console only)

Tags: objective-c

My NSTimer (startTimer) works fine. It runs the selected method (runTimer) but whatever code I place in the (runTimer) it does not increment. For example if I run the code as below it prints out 5 times but does not increment x. Any ideas - thanks

```
- (void)startTimer {
    self.timer  = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self     selector:@selector(runTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]];
    }
- (void)runTimer:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    int x;
    x++;
    NSLog(@"int x = %i",x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with static variables in Objective-C methods as suggested by smparkes. They're shared between all instances of that class, so if you've got multiple instances of whatever object this code is from, his answer *won't* act the way you expect. You'd be better off with an instance variable, because each instance will have its own variable, without affecting other instances:

In your .h:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    int x;
}
```

Then in your `-runTimer:` method:

```
- (void)runTimer:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    NSLog(@"int x = %i", x++);
}
```

If you are guaranteed that there will only be one instance of whatever this class is (e.g. it's a singleton), a static variable inside the `-runTimer:` method will work, but I'd recommend using an instance variable or @property as it's better programming practice.

Comment: Thanks all - I understand now. Ive just created an ivar int (int num) set properties and the re-run code with self.num+=1 and all works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please make sure you accept the answer that best helped you by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Doing so gives future answerers more of an incentive to help.

Answer (score 2):

You get a new `x` every time `runTimer` is called. If you make it static

```
static int x;
```

it'll act the way you expect. For cleanliness, I'd also initialize it:

```
static int x = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

runTimer declares x every time, i.e. it creates a new variable, set to 0, increments it and prints it out, so it will always be the same value. you need a variable outside the scope of that method in order to increment it